# Indentation of pformat() output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pprint

I have a function that uses [`pformat()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pprint.html?highlight=pformat#pprint.pformat) to convert a dictionary to a string (*irrelevant*: string will be later inserted with `write()` in a `.py` file).

So `MY_DCT = {1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 33}` would become a string like this:

```
MY_DCT = {
    1: 11,
    2: 22,
    3: 33}
```

There are 2 requirements for the function:

1. Dict items must be displayed after the first line.
2. Elements have to be indented by 4 whitespaces.

Here is the function:

```
import pprint    

def f(obj_name, obj_body_as_dct):

    body = '{\n' + pprint.pformat(obj_body_as_dct, indent=4, width=1)[1:]
    name_and_equal_sign = obj_name + ' = '

    return name_and_equal_sign + body + '\n\n'


d = {1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 33}

print(f('MY_DCT', d))
```

If `indent=0` i get this string:

```
MY_DCT = {
1: 11,
2: 22,
3: 33}
```

If `indent=4` i get this string:

```
MY_DCT = {
   1: 11,
    2: 22,
    3: 33}
```

I checked the [parameters](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pprint.html?highlight=pformat#pprint.PrettyPrinter) of `pformat()` but i couldn't figure out how to make the correct number of whitespaces appear on each line.

I know i can use `replace()`, `+' '` etc., to fix the string, but i m wondering where does that extra whitespace come from and if i can get rid of it by setting correctly the parameters (if that is even possible, that is).

*Note:* If there is a better way to achieve the above, do let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default value of `indent` in `pformat` is 1, so that keys appear one under the other.

For example, `pformat(d, indent=0, width=1)` would result in this string:

```
{1: 11,
2: 22,
3: 33}
```

`indent=1`:

```
{1: 11,
 2: 22,
 3: 33}
```

and `indent=2`:

```
{ 1: 11,
  2: 22,
  3: 33}
```

One less whitespace always on the first line.

---

Since the goal was to display dict elements after the first line, and have all elements indented by 4 spaces, adding a single whitespace before the first element and using `indent=4` would work for some dicts (as suggested by @logic).

However dicts like `d = {1: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 2: 22, 3: 33}` would look rather ugly, since `indent` would affect the appearance of dicts with depth greater than 1 as well:

```
MY_DCT = {
    1: {   'a': 1,
           'b': 2},
    #    ^
    #    |
    # ugly
    2: 22,
    3: 33}
```

---

The most appealing solution (for the data i m working on) is keeping `indent=1` and adding 3 whitespaces for first element, and 4 whitespaces for the rest.

```
def f(obj_name, given_dct):
    """
    Converts given dct (body) to a pretty formatted string.
    Resulting string used for file writing.

    Args:
        obj_name: (str) name of the dict
    Returns:
        (str)
    """

    string = pp.pformat(given_dct, width=1)[1:]

    new_str = ''
    for num, line in enumerate(string.split('\n')):
        if num == 0:
            # (pprint module always inserts one less whitespace for first line)
            # (indent=1 is default, giving everything one extra whitespace)
            new_str += ' '*4 + line + '\n'
        else:
            new_str += ' '*3 + line + '\n'

    return obj_name + ' = {\n' + new_str


s = f(obj_name='MY_DCT', given_dct=d)
```

Resulting in this string:

```
MY_DCT = {
    1: {'a': 'aa',
        'b': [1,
              2,
              3]},
    2: 22,
    3: 33}
```

Answer (score 2):

The **parameters** are not the issue with your printing. The problem occurs when you add newlines (`'\n'`). As you can see from this example:

```
import pprint    

def f(obj_name, obj_body_as_dct):

    body = '{' + pprint.pformat(obj_body_as_dct, indent=4, width=1, depth=1)[1:]
    name_and_equal_sign = obj_name + ' = ' + '\n'

    return '"""' + name_and_equal_sign + body + '"""' + '\n\n'


d = {1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 33}

print(f('MY_DCT', d))
```

This outputs:

```
"""MY_DCT = 
{   1: 11,
    2: 22,
    3: 33}"""
```

The newlines, and the addition of a '`{`' in the first row of printing is why only the first row of your output seems to be offset by a small space.

**UPDATE #1**:

After a bit of tinkering with these values, I was able to match your desired output:

```
import pprint    

def f(obj_name, obj_body_as_dct):

    body = pprint.pformat(obj_body_as_dct, indent=4, width=1, depth=1)[1:]
    name_and_equal_sign = obj_name 

    return '"""' + name_and_equal_sign + ' = ' + '{' + '\n ' + body +'"""'  + '\n\n'  
                                                        # ^ I added a space in this newline

d = {1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 33}

print(f('MY_DCT', d))
```

The above code outputs:

```
"""MY_DCT = { 
    1: 11,
    2: 22,
    3: 33}"""
```

So, in essence, you just needed one space in a newline character (shown in code).

**UPDATE #2**:

Following your suggestion in the comments:

> Try this: `print(pp.pformat({1:11, 2:22, 3:33}, indent=0, width=1))`,
>   with indent going from 0 to 2. You ll notice, it applies one less
>   whitespace on the first line. It is the way `pformat()` is built. -@user 5061

I tried this:

```
import pprint as pp

for i in range(0,3):
    print(pp.pformat({1:11, 2:22, 3:33}, indent=i, width=1))
```

And it gave me this output:

```
{1: 11,     #Indent = 0 Each entry (except 1) is indented by 0 spaces, because the "{" operator is in the way. 
2: 22,
3: 33}
{1: 11,     #Indent = 1 Each entry is indented by 1 spaces
 2: 22,
 3: 33}
{ 1: 11,    #Indent = 2 Each entry is indented by 2 spaces
  2: 22,
  3: 33}
```

As you can see, the problem is still with this:  "`{`"
If that wasn't there, then the indents would be even throughout. The function `pformat()` was coded to adjust for that character.

Comment: Try this: `print(pp.pformat({1:11, 2:22, 3:33}, indent=0, width=1))`, with `indent` going from 0 to 2. You ll notice, it applies one less whitespace on the first line. It is the way `pformat()` is built.

Comment: @user5061 Did you try using my Python code though? I was able to fix your problem with just a space.

Answer (score 0):

[Logic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4669462/logic) has you covered as to why you are having the indentation issue. As (*IMO*) a more concise approach however, you can make use of [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html). This output is assuming that by *elements* you mean dictionary elements:

```
import json
obj_name = 'MY_DCT = '
obj_body_as_dct = {1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 33}

stringy = "\"\"\"" + obj_name + "{" \
          + str(json.dumps(obj_body_as_dct, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))[1:] + "\"\"\""
print(stringy)
```

**Outputs:**

```
"""MY_DCT = {
    "1": 11,
    "2": 22,
    "3": 33
}"""
```

Comment: The string will be inserted in a `.py` file. This output would be invalid syntax.

Comment: @user5061 Your desired output is *exactly* as shown in your first display? I can edit if so, and place in a string.

Comment: Your output is _not_ the same as the one i have in my question. If you copy that output, and insert it in a py file, you would get a syntax error.

Comment: @user5061 I formatted my code to get you a string ;) (got you covered)

Comment: @user5061 I understand what you mean, you wanted to put it literally in a .py file. Edited to do so, please see updated answer